# How to track in Google Analytics registrations coming from Google AdWords ads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, tracking, click-tracking

I created a campaign in `Google AdWords` and some ads in it and gave them URLs like

```
mydomain.tld/registration/?utm_campaign=mycampaing&ad=x
mydomain.tld/registration/?utm_campaign=mycampaing&ad=y
mydomain.tld/registration/?utm_campaign=mycampaing&ad=z
```

All ads lead to the registration page.

A registration is a visit of the page

```
mydomain.tld/registration-completed/?user={ID}
```

So I can track the registrations in Google Analytics. I just go to `Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages` and filter the pages to `registration-completed`.

But how can I see, **how many** and **which users** have registered, after they came from an ad of a campaign, e.g. `utm_campaign`? And how can I also track this for a single ad of the campaign, e.g. `x`?

Answer (score 1):

To track registrations in Google Analytics, you need to set up a goal.  You can do so by clicking "Admin" -> "Goals" -> "New Goal".  You will want to create a new goal with the following details:

- **Name**: registration
- **Destination**: begins with "/registration-completed/"

After you do this, the report in "Acquisition" -> "Campaigns" will automatically begin tracking the number of users that get to this goal as part of this campaign.

To track different ads on the campaign you will need to set a parameter to which Google Analytics pays attention.  It will ignore your `ad` parameter, so you need to use a parameter that it uses.   The [Google Analytics URL Builder Tool](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) has a list of parameters that you can use:

- Campaign Source (`utm_source`): referrer (google, citysearch, newsletter4)
- Campaign Medium (`utm_medium`): marketing medium (cpc, banner, email)
- Campaign Term  (`utm_term`): identify the paid keywords
- Campaign Content (`utm_content`): use to differentiate ads

It would appear that `utm_content` would be the most appropriate.  The problem is that Google Analytics doesn't allow you to deep dive on this parameter that I can tell.  If you are not otherwise using them, I would suggest setting `utm_source` or `utm_medium` instead.  Google Analytics does allow you to click through from the campaign report to see your campaigns by source and medium.

Google Analytic's terms of service preclude tracking individual users.  There will be no way of seeing which users are created through your campaigns with Google Analytics.

Comment: oogle suggests the [auto-tagging](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1733663) instead of the manual set up `utm_*` parameters. So I'm checking different variants. But you wrote a good post, thank you & +1 for your answer!